# Error when booting iPod Video 5G after installing SD card

Tags: boot, filesystems, sd-card, format, ipod

I bought a used iPod video (A1136) as a project piece to install an SSD in and run Rockbox. I bought a ZIF>CF>SD adapter and am using a 128GB SD Card. I got everything connected correctly and the device does power when I plug it into the front USB port on my PC.

Only problem as you can see from the gif 
[iPod error](https://i.imgur.com/ahi2W88.gif)
that I linked, is I am stuck in a boot loop. holding Menu+center button and play/pause+center button does nothing.

I suspect the filesystem may need to be modified. It was originally formatted as exFAT and I also tried NTFS but got the same error both times.

Any ideas? does anyone know what filesystem the iPod uses?

Comment: Use iTunes to format it. It will format differently depending on whether you use Mac or PC for the task.

Comment: My problem is it's not mounting in the first place. Is there any tool where I can format the SD card manually? I can just stick it in my laptop.

Comment: You probably need to force it into disk mode - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201544

Comment: holding the play/pause and center button when the "please connect to itunes" screen appears does nothing. holding the back/forwards buttons when the apple logo appears during the loop does nothing. 

I'm worried that the battery might be shot because despite the iPod charging for two days straight, disconnecting the power cable immediately shuts it off.